# EOL Error in Python

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I am having the following error, can someone explain to me what can I do to fix it.

```
def increment(i):
    request =("https://www.minsalud.gov.co/sites/rid/Paginas/freesearchresults.aspx?k=&k=Salud%20Mental%20Legislacion#k=%2CSalud%20Mental%20Legislacion=+ 1"+ i+")
```

> EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: check there's only one `"` at the end of your line, either close it with another `"` or remove it altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing `"` and `)` at the end of your line

```
request =("https://www.minsalud.gov.co/sites/rid/Paginas/freesearchresults.aspx?k=&k=Salud%20Mental%20Legislacion#k=%2CSalud%20Mental%20Legislacion=+ 1"+ i+")")
```